# Calling method on modalview from popover controller

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have an iPad application which consists of a splitviewcontroller - From the detailview of the splitview i open a modalviewcontroller(NearbyViewController) which has a button that shows a popover(RadiusViewController) with a picker. This works just fine, but when i select a value in the picker i want to call a method on the modalview controller, but i can't figure out how to do this?

My "NearbyViewController" imports the "RadiusViewController.h" because i access certain data in the "RadiusViewController", but i also need to be able to send data from the RadiusViewController back to NearbyViewController, but if i import the NearbyViewController.h file in the RadiusView then i get compilation errors due to them trying to import eachother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem and it's very easy to solve. The solution is simply to make the imports in the .m files instead. If you need the type to be known in the .h file, you simply use forward declaration.

```
@class ClassName;
```

It's as simple as that.

**EDIT:** A more thorough explanation:

Generally in the .h file the methods and properties of the class doesn't need to be known. All you need to do is tell the compiler that there is a class named `ClassName`. The compiler doesn't need to know anything else about the class at that point. In the .m file you will need to know the methods and properties of that class or you will not be able to use it. So in the .m file you import the class.

Just to be clear:

```
// SomeClass.h
@class ClassName;

// SomeClass.m
#import "ClassName.h"
```

This is called forward declaration. You can google it to learn more or read an introductory book on programming. It's a very basic programming concept and it's important that you learn it.

Comment: I've already tried that and it doesn't quite work. It can see the class allright, but it doesn't recognize any of the methods or instance variables that i have declared in that class. But if i include the header file it recognizes methods and variables just fine, so something is different when using the @class name;.

Comment: @Milk78 What you are describing is exactly how `@class` and `#import` works. Maybe I should update my answer to explain it further.

Comment: Thanks alot for the added explanation :) Scary thing is i have been developing for 10 years and I have 5 apps in the appstore without knowing the details about forward declaration - Maybe it's time to learn it :D